# Getting system to boot in headless mode set-up without display problems

Tags: monitor, remote-desktop, headless

Previously I had Ubuntu 11.04 and I could boot with no monitor attached.

Now I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 with autologin and I've found that is incapable of booting correctly if the monitor isn't attached.

Is there a way to "force" Ubuntu to "remember" last monitor attached or to define a virtual one to allow a "normal" booting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

Comment: @john I've tried to clarify your question for others, but let me know (or re-edit) if I've gone the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this :

go to directory :

```
cd /etc/X11/

cp xorg.conf xorg.bak

sudo gedit xorg.conf
```

Look for this section "Device" in the file, and update the file to be like this :

```
Section "Device"
     Identifier "Configured Device"
     Driver "vesa"
EndSection
```

If you dont find this section then put it at the top of the file.

Try to keep the complete file consistent.

More Details step by step guide : [Running Ubuntu without monitor](http://www.bsntech.com/bsntech-blog-mainmenu-321/computers-mainmenu-281/6201-running-ubuntu-without-a-monitor-attached-x-fails.html)

Comment: Thanks Vikash, my driver is already vesa, and it isn't working. Here is my xorg.conf:  Section "Device"  
Identifier "Configured Video Device"  
Driver "vesa"  
Option "NoDDCValue" "True"  
EndSection  

Section "Monitor"  
Identifier "Configured Monitor"  
HorizSync 31.5-48.5  
VertRefresh 50-70  
EndSection  

Section "Screen"  
Identifier "Default Screen"  
Monitor "Configured Monitor"  
Device "Configured Video Device"  
DefaultDepth 24  
SubSection "Display"  
Depth 24  
Modes "1024x768"  
EndSubSection  
EndSection

Comment: Try and change the < Identifier  "Card0" > and see if it works...

Comment: Nope, and sorry about the raw xorg.conf I couldn't figure it how to format it properly.

Comment: Anyone know why this feature is broken from previous versions? Is this a bug?